# eduroam wifi login RP3b vs RPI4

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie, pi-4, raspbian-buster, wpa-supplicant

I was wondering if there is any difference with the RPI3b and the RPI4 to login to eduroam network (WPA-EAP)?

I have 3 rpi3b and i connect to eduroam **without** any issue. On th RPi 3B I have Raspbian Jessie running and on the RPi 4B Raspbian Buster (others will not work of course). Eduroam is an Enterprise wifi network. It is available on universities campus, libraries and governmental research organisation all over the world... It use the WPA-EAP.

I use the following wpa_supllicant.conf file:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=AU

network={
ssid="eduroam"
key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
identity="myID"
password="myPassword"
}
```

when i use the exact same file on a RPI4, it doesn't work!!
The wifi does got got connected, and i even got an IP (see pics) but internet ping return an error.

[image: screen capture RPI4]

And to top it off, the 'connection' is very instable, it last 20s max before it reset...

Im clueless, does somebody has an idea where as it works with a RPI3B and it doesn't with a RPI4?

Cheers

Comment: No you **DON'T** have an IP address - what you have is a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address). There ARE differences between Pi3 and Pi4 (the latter supports 5GHz networks) but there should be no difference in networking configuration. Are all devices running Buster?

Comment: @Milliways. 
I didn't know about link-local adress. What you saying is I am connected to my local network, but i can't get out of it?

Good point with the OS, the RPI3B all run on Strech, RPI4 run on Buster. But what would it be different?

Comment: Follow the link [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) are NOT routable - they are primarily used for configuration but support limited functionality on **directly connected** devices. You need to inspect the logs to see why.

Comment: What ip address do you get for wlan0 on a RPi3B?

Comment: @ingo 
On RPI3B i get 150.229.196.251

Comment: Curious, that is a public ip address, used by provider on the internet. Anyway, on the RPi 4B  you use Raspbian Buster. What operating system do you use on the RPi 3B? What is eduroam?

Comment: @ingo I have Jesse on the 3B.
Eduroam is Enterprise wifi network. Is is available on universities campus, libraries and governmental research organisation all over the world... It use the WPA-EAP.

Comment: Please next time add additional information to your question :-). You can edit it. Not all user read comments to understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enterprise WiFi Networking is broken on Buster. You need to revert to an earlier version of WPA_supplicant. Try searching for pi4 PEAP authentication failure to find out how to revert to stretch version of wpasupplicant

Comment: Do you have a source (link) for your statement?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the RPi 4B is that it is associated to the wifi network with ssid="eduroam" but does not get an ip address from the DHCP server on the network 150.229.196.0/16. If the network stack does not find a DHCP server it will give a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) to the interface but that does not fit to the network address range and cannot work.

So you have to look, why the RPi 4B does not get an ip address from the DHCP server contrary to the RPi 3B. Raspbian Jessie is old-old-stable and its support ends at 2019-12-31. Raspbian Buster is two versions later so I'm not surprised that it may behave different in particular if you use emulation from **systemd** (I don't know if you do but with Jessie it is likely). In [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/) you will find in the last sentence:

> Note that there are some areas where systemd currently provides a certain amount of compatibility where we expect this compatibility to be removed eventually.

With the available information I cannot say much about the reason of your problem. WPA-EAP can be configured in many ways and is mainly dependent on the setup of the enterprises network. You have to get needed information from there. You may find some hints from the examples at the end of the file `/usr/share/doc/wpa_supplicant/examples/wpa_supplicant.conf`.